# ThreeJS Shader Dynamic Texture

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I have this shader code below. I want to add a new uniform for another texture and make it that it would be applied to the vertices that is divisible by 4.

```
uniform vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {

    vec4 outColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );

    if ( outColor.a < 0.5 ) discard;

    gl_FragColor = outColor * vec4( color * vColor.xyz, 0.5 );

    float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;
    const vec3 fogColor = vec3( 0.0 );

    float fogFactor = smoothstep( 200.0, 600.0, depth );
    gl_FragColor = mix( gl_FragColor, vec4( fogColor, gl_FragColor.w ), fogFactor );
}
```

I want to add a condition something like `index % 4 === 0 ? firstTexture : secondTexture` but I do not know how to get the vertex index and perform a modulo operator in the shader language.

Answer (score 3):

WebGL GLSL does not provide a vertex index, so you'll have to provide that data manually. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658031/in-int-gl-vertexid-causing-error-with-three-js).

The modulus operator in GLSL is a function called [mod()](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf).